# Где находится круглая иконка приложения, отображаемая в backstack?

Tags: android, icon

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где находится круглая иконка (на картинке значок Google) в Android Studio? Я загрузил в своем приложении кастомную иконку через Image Asset. Везде кроме этого места отображаются мои иконки, а здесь стоит стандартная с головой андроида.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел место, где лежит такой файл. Он находится в папке

```
res/mipmap/ic_launcher/ic_launcher.png
```

Вначале думал, что в папке ic_launcher_round, но это не так.
На своем эмуляторе я определил, что при удалении одного файла кастомная иконка заменяется на стандартную (в моем случае это был png-файл с разрешением xxxhdpi).